# Does Nexus OSS support proxying of Ivy repos?

Tags: ivy, nexus

It's [clear from Sonatype's website](http://blog.sonatype.com/2012/06/does-nexus-pro-support-ant-ivy-builds-yes-it-does/) that Nexus Pro supports proxying of Ivy repos.

However, the [Nexus documentation](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/) does not mention this, and anyway is never clear whether it's describing Nexus OSS or Nexus Pro.

Does Nexus OSS support proxying of Ivy repos?

Comment: Hi @armand, Were you able to get a solution to use Nexus 3 OOS as a proxy for ivy repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you mentioned answers your question:

> No. Ivy repositories are not supported by Nexus OSS or Pro at this
>   time. However in most cases Maven repositories are the preferred
>   choice mostly for interoperability with other build tools like Maven,
>   SBT and others. More detail can be found in
>   http://books.sonatype.com/nexu...

Nexus is effectively the reference implementation of a Maven repository. Whether one likes it or not it has become the de facto standard for the storage of Java binary artefacts.

Thankfully ivy is well able to support both the upload and download of artefacts from Maven repositories. Secondly there is no repository management software available for ivy repositories, so really I cannot think of a reason not to use Nexus. It allows me to share my ANT build with other java projects built using Maven, Gradle, SBT, etc....